# How to decode a text file

Tags: python, twitter, encoding, tweepy

I have this code here and it work perfectly.

```
# encoding=utf8
#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
import sys
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""

#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        #save data
        with open('debate_data.txt', 'a') as tf:
            tf.write((data).decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8'))

        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter     Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords:     'Bernier', 'Rossello', 'Bernabe'
    stream.filter(track=['Bernier', 'Rosselló', 'Rossello', 'Bernabe', 'Lúgaro', 'Lugaro', 'María de Lourdes', 'Maria de Lourdes', 'Cidre'])
```

But when I run this other piece of code I get the wrong answer.

```
import json
import io

#save the tweets to this path
tweets_data_path = 'debate_data.txt'

tweets_data = []
with io.open(tweets_data_path, 'r') as tweets_file:
    for line in tweets_file:
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            tweets_data.append(tweet)
        except:
            continue

print len(tweets_data)
```

There are 42,188 Tweets on that file, but when I run the code Im only getting 291. I think is something with the encoding/decoding but I cant figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

I ran this example without any of the encoding/decoding and it worked perfectly.

http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/

Answer (score 2):

The reason of only getting 291 is the `json.loads()` throw some errors and `except` continue it.

I suggest you print the error just like:

```
except Exception as err:
    print err
    continue
```

now you know the error reason, and solve it.

Are you sure the format of data inside `debate_data.txt` are `json` ?

Answer (score 2):

As agnewee said, I also recommend:

```
try:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
except Exception as err:
    print err # or use log to see what happen
else:
    tweets_data.append(tweet)
```

Comment: ok, I did what you guys told me, and got a lot of errors, that I'm gonna try to fix. Here are some of them: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 columna 272 (char 271) Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 202 (char 201) Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 274 (char 273) Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 145 (char 144) No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675401/cant-read-json-file-in-python

Comment: Such errors I had when a file that I wanted to import had delimiter characters not only as delimiters, but also as characters in the cells - for example, a sentence with a comma.